# Azure HTTP Triggere Function Empty Body

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have 2 functions running on my azure function app. One of the functions is cosmodb triggered and calls another function which is http triggered. When testing locally everything works as expected but when publishing the body does not seem to pass to the HTTP triggered function correctly.

HTTP Function:

```
 try:
        req_body = json.loads(req.get_json())
        logger.info(req_body)
        run_process(req_body)
        return func.HttpResponse(status_code=200)
    except OSError as exception:
        logger.error(
            f"An error occurred while processing the request: {exception}")
        return func.HttpResponse(exception, status_code=400)
```

CosmoDB Triggered Function:

```
def post_document(document: dict):
    # Serialize the document to a JSON string
    json_data = json.dumps(document, default=str)
    logger.info(f"posting document: {json_data}")
    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", URL, headers=headers, json=json_data, timeout=10)
    assert response.status_code == 200, f'ER POST failed {response.content}'

    logger.info(f'ER POST request successful')
```

The weird thing is that when I hardcode the data it seems to work fine, when I copy and paste the data returned by this line "logger.info(f"posting document: {json_data}")" and hard code that it works as well. Any ideas why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I got the desired results after following the below.

*init .py*

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import logger

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        logger.logger.info(req_body)
        return func.HttpResponse(status_code=200)
    except OSError as exception:
        logger.error(
            f"An error occurred while processing the request: {exception}")
        return func.HttpResponse(exception, status_code=400)
```

*requirements.txt*

```
azure-functions==1.13.3
logger==1.4
```

Since JSON data is received to http function I've replace `req_body = json.loads(req.get_json())` with `req_body = req.get_json()`.

*Results when the function runs locally*

[image]

*Results when the function is deployed*

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. For me using the specific *azure-functions* version did not solve the issue. For me what solved the issue is using *https* instead of *http* in the function url.